# Why is mysqli_query being evaluated as boolean instead of result set

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What should be a simple mySQL call from PHP is generating the mySQL error `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Here's the code:

```
$updateSQL = "UPDATE content SET type='type1', updated_by='Fred', date_updated = NOW() WHERE id=123";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username,password, $database);

$update = mysqli_query($mysqli, $updateSQL) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row_update = mysqli_fetch_assoc($update);
$totalRows_update = mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);
```

At first I thought the problem was the `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))`, but I get the same error even if I comment that part out.  When I check `$update` with `gettype($update)`, it does show a type of boolean, but I don't understand why.

BTW, the update query itself seems to execute with no problems.

Comment: can you show whats inside $updateSQL

Comment: Typically it's an error in your SQL statement, which you don't show

Comment: if you are doing an update...you dont have nothing to fetch, I think

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I think zerkms is correct.  Since it's an update query, there's no result set, so the fetch_assoc doesn't make any sense and probably is generating the error.  The actual query isn't missing the semicolon.

Comment: Ok. I edited your question and added the missing semi-colon. In the future, please post actual production code, and everything relevant to the problem. It'll leave all the guesswork out of things. ;-)

Comment: Please try comment `$row_update = mysqli_fetch_assoc($update)` and you wont get more errors

Comment: It is being evaluated as `boolean` because you did not bother [reading the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues).

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not returning a recordset in you query you don't have to fetch any result, My advice is remove `$row_update = mysqli_fetch_assoc($update);` line